# Dojo equivalent for jquery's .data() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

Simple question:

Is there a Dojo equivalent to jQuery's .data() functionality?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For access to the *data* DOM attribute use [dojo/dom-attr](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/dom-attr.html):

```
require(["dojo/dom-attr"], function(domAttr){
    result = domAttr.set("myNode", "data-myattribute", "myValue");
});
```

For a true storage interface use [dojo/store](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/store.html#dojo-store):

```
require(["dojo/store/Memory", "dojo/store/Observable"], function(Memory, Observable){
    var store = Observable(new Memory({ data: someData }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dojo.attr(node, attr, value);
```

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/attr.html

Comment: That's not really the same thing is it?